# Does the order of columns has a significant effect on INSERT?

Tags: mysql, query, innodb, performance, insert, query-performance

Do we experience a noticeable difference in performance for these two queries?

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) ...
```

and

```
INSERT INTO table (col5, col3, col1, col2, col4) ...
```

Do we need to arrange `INSERT` columns according to the order of columns in the table?

Comment: Are you suffering from premature optimization syndrome?

Comment: :D something like that! I'm just curious to learn!

Comment: Obviously the order in which the columns are specified doesn't affect performance. Because if you were the compiler you could just rehash the whole thing to represent it in its proper order which the compiler obviously does by matching names with the proper places on the data page. Things are a bit complex on the lower level so do you really think mysql guys messed up with this triviality?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you don't need to gave the columns in the same order. Not least, table order may not reflect actual on-disk order (this is 100% true for SQL Server, and I'm sure MySQL is the same)

Unless your OCD itch needs scratched

Comment: I mainly keep it in the same order for consistency.  Copy/paste FTW!

Comment: @DForck42: agree. Also see my tip here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/729221/27535